# Find minimum and maximum of $\frac {m_a}{b+c}+\frac {m_b}{c+a}+ \frac {m_c}{a+b} $

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

For $\triangle ABC$ are $AB=c, BC=a, CA=b$ and $AM_1=m_a, AM_2=m_b, AM_3=m_c$ are medians. Find minimum and maximum of
$$\frac {m_a}{b+c}+\frac {m_b}{c+a}+ \frac {m_c}{a+b} $$

#### My work so far:

$$\frac{b+c}2>m_a$$ Then

$$\frac {m_a}{b+c}+\frac {m_b}{c+a}+ \frac {m_c}{a+b} <\frac32$$

Comment: HINT: use that $$m_a\geq \frac{b^2+c^2}{4R}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=b=1$ and $c\rightarrow2^-$ then $m_a=m_b\rightarrow\frac{3}{2}$ and $m_c\rightarrow0^+$.

Thus, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{m_a}{b+c}\rightarrow1.$

We'll prove that it's an infimum.

Indeed, let $a=y+z$, $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}}{b+c}\geq2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{4x(x+y+z)+(y-z)^2}}{2x+y+z}\geq2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\tfrac{4x(x+y+z)+(y-z)^2}{(2x+y+z)^2}+\tfrac{2\sqrt{(4x(x+y+z)+(y-z)^2)(4y(x+y+z)+(x-z)^2)}}{(2x+y+z)(2y+x+z)}\right)\geq4.$$
Now, by C-S and AM-GM
$$\sqrt{(4x(x+y+z)+(y-z)^2)(4y(x+y+z)+(x-z)^2)}\geq$$
$$\geq4\sqrt{xy}(x+y+z)+(x-z)(y-z)\geq8xy+(x-z)(y-z).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\tfrac{4x(x+y+z)+(y-z)^2}{(2x+y+z)^2}+\tfrac{16xy+2(x-z)(y-z)}{(2x+y+z)(2y+x+z)}\right)\geq4$$ or
$$\sum_{sym}\left(2x^6+12x^5y-3x^4y^2-13x^3y^3+48x^4yz+218x^3y^2z+\frac{235}{3}x^2y^2z^2\right)\geq0$$ or
$$4\sum_{cyc}(x^6-x^4y^2-x^4z^2+x^2y^2z^2)+$$
$$+\sum_{sym}(12x^5y+x^4y^2-13x^3y^3)+\sum_{sym}\left(48x^4yz+218x^3y^2z+\frac{229}{3}x^2y^2z^2\right)\geq0,$$
which is true by Schur and Muirhead.

Let $a=b$ and $c\rightarrow0^+$.

Thus, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{m_a}{b+c}\rightarrow\frac{3}{2},$ which says that your estimation is the best.

Done!